# Install specific Vue component from app (like installing specific Lodash function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, node-modules

I created blank Vue3 + Vite project using

```
npm init vue@3
```

I am wondering how can I install my components from `src/components` like for example in lodash library:
`npm i lodash.debounce` or `my-app/component`

Thank you!

I have tried to create index.js file in src and export components:

```
import Button from "@/components/Button/Button.vue";
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header.vue";

export default {
  Button,
  Header
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Components are installed only in one case - when they are published on the NPM registry and you want to use them in multiple projects. In all other cases you just put the `*.vue` file of your component inside `src/components` folder of your project and then import them where you need them. If you want to make them globally available - you can register them globally with `app.component('MyComponentTag', importedComponent);` - see https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I want to use them in multiple projects! My project is something like ui-components like `ant-design-vue`, so they will need to use in lots of projects. I'd really appreciate if you could send me the link to the guide to publish all the components in NPM separately, i googled this but it seems like i did not find the correct guide.

Comment: Google is your best friend - and it does not require a graduation :)) A simple search gives plenty of results - https://itnext.io/create-a-vue-js-component-library-as-a-module-part-1-a1116e632751, https://medium.com/justfrontendthings/how-to-create-and-publish-your-own-vuejs-component-library-on-npm-using-vue-cli-28e60943eed3, https://www.thisdot.co/blog/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-vue-component-library-to-npm, https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-test-bundle-vue-components-library-8c4828ab7b00

Comment: Maybe you did not catch me. I want the components in my library be published in separate npm package, but within one repo, so you can install separate components from library like `npm i @org/scope/component`

Comment: I doubt that NPM supports such kind of sub-packaging. I believe that if you want each component to be available completely separately from the rest of components - you will need a separate NPM package for each component. Since you refer to Lodash and their per-method NPM packages - you can probably do the same but imagine if this was the case with Vuetify, Quasar, ElementUI, Buify and other component libraries for Vue. Would you as a developer prefer to install a separate NPM package for each component - or prefer to import the few components you need from a single library/package?

Comment: You can create a subrepo for the repository that exports all of the components of the library.

Comment: Actually I found a solution, there is my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it is called Monorepos, Lerna implements the thing I need.
[Here is the link](https://lerna.js.org/)